# ObservableCollection CollectionChanged

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция

```
public MvxObservableCollection<Note> Notes = new MvxObservableCollection<Note>(await App.DataBase.GetItemsAsync());
Notes.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
```

При добавлении элемента `Notes.Add(item);` не вызывается метод `OnCollectionChanged`

```
void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Note newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                newItem.ActionSheetEventHandler += ActionSheetExecute;
            }
        }
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (Note oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    oldItem.ActionSheetEventHandler -= ActionSheetExecute;
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: `public MvxObservableCollection<Note> Notes` это не коллекция, это неинициализированное поле класса. Где ваша коллекция и как вы на нее подписываетесь?

Comment: SuppressEvents вызывайте?

Comment: поле инициализировано `Notes = new MvxObservableCollection<Note>(await App.DataBase.GetItemsAsync());`(обновил вопрос)